# how do you clear an entire datagridview column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView with a few columns, how do you clear the data out of an entire column?

Comment: Loop through all the rows, clearing only the cell that is contained in that column.

Comment: winforms or webforms?

Comment: win forms, there is no default clear function for a column though?

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop the rows and clear the cell:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.Rows) 
{
    myRow.Cells[0].Value = null; // assuming you want to clear the first column
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I know it's been a while but here's what I've done.. I just copy the column into a temporary variable, remove the column from the datagridview and finally insert the temporary column into the datagridview... This way, I don't have to loop though all the rows...

Something like:

```
 var tmp = dgv.Columns[3];
 dgv.Columns.Remove(dgv.Columns[3]);
 dgv.Columns.Insert(3, tmp);
```

I also code an Extension to have an easier to read code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ClearColumn(this DataGridView dgv, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (dgv.Columns != null && dgv.Columns.Count - 1 >= columnIndex)
        {
            var tmpCol = dgv.Columns[columnIndex];
            dgv.Columns.Remove(dgv.Columns[columnIndex]);
            dgv.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, tmpCol);
        }
    }
}
```

Just use it like this:

```
Datagridview1.ClearColumn(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Suppose that you want to clear column 0.

```
var myColumn = myDataGridView.Columns[0];

for (int i = 0; i < myColumn.Cells.Count; i++)
  column.Cells[i].Value = null;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work FYI, `DataGridViewColumn` doesn't have a `Cells` indexer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

or

If you're using a `BindingSource`

```
bindingSource1.Clear();
```

or If you want to clear your `DataGridView Columns`

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```

Answer (score -2):

To clear a specific column

```
dataGridView1.Rows[<ROW_INDEX>].Cells[<CELL_INDEX>].Value = null
```

Comment: Did you try it? As per my reading, this should clear the value of a specific cell into a specific row